# Array Search of Generics java

Tags: java, arrays, search, generics

I am trying to search an array of any data type (Int, Strings, Chars, etc...) to see if there exist an element that matches the one you input. You should return the index of the matching element. There are two classes being used.

The error I get is:

```
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method find(Object[], Object) from the type ArraySearch"
```

Its suggestion is to make the method static, however, doing that gives me an error in the Search class:

```
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E".
```

**Search Class:**

```
public class ArraySearch<E> {
public int find (E[] array, E item) {
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if (array[i].equals(item)) {
              System.out.println("There is a element " + array[i] + 
                      " at index " + i);
              index = i;
              break;
          }
      }
      return index;
  }
}
```

**Runner Class:**

```
public class ArraySearchRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] strings = new String[]{"Jim", "Tim", "Bob", "Greg"};
    Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    ArraySearch.find(strings, "Bob");
    ArraySearch.find(ints, 4);


}
}
```

What is the best solution in this case?

Thanks,

Comment: Yah, but I wrote everything above myself. Just unsure how to deal with implementing the parts above.

Comment: @chrylis. Doesn't matter, as OP has shown his attempt.

Comment: @RohitJain If this weren't homework, I'd just say to use `contains()`. ;-)

Comment: @chrylis. Of course. But there is not `contains()` method for arrays. But I see what you are talking about.

Comment: `Arrays.asList( a ).contains( e )`

Comment: The type parameter `E` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of your class to invoke the instance methods. Something like this:

```
class Demo {
    public void show() { }
}

new Demo().show();
```

Now, I leave it to you to instantiate your generic class.

Also, your `find()` method is broken. If an element is not found, it will return an `index = 0`. Which is a valid index in array. You should rather initialize the `index` to `-1`:

```
int index = -1;
```

Regarding your attempt to make the method static, it will give you error, because the type parameters are not applicable for `static` members of a class.

From [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Where%20is%20a%20type%20parameter%20visible%20%28or%20invisible%29?):

> The scope of a class's type parameter is the entire definition of the class, except any static members or static initializers of the class. This means that the type parameters cannot be used in the declaration of static fields or methods or in static nested types or static initializers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class ArraySearch<E> 
        {
        public int find (E[] array, E item) 
        {
              int c = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
              {
                  if (array[i].equals(item)) 
                  {
                      c++;
                       
                  }
              }
              System.out.println("There is a element " + item + 
                      " repeated " + c + " time(s)");
              return c;
          }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        
            String[] strings = new String[]{"Jim", "Tim", "Bob", "Greg","Bob"};
            String[] strings2 = new String[]{"Jim", "Tim", "Bob", "Greg","Bob"};
            Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,2};
            Double[] dbl= new Double[] {1.2,3.6,8.4,8.4,8.4,3.6};
            ArraySearch arr = new ArraySearch();
            arr.find(strings, "Bob");
            arr.find(strings, "Tim");
            arr.find(ints, 2);
            arr.find(dbl, 8.4);
            enter code here
        
        }
        }
```